# Openssl is not supported

Tags: reactjs

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\REACT\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\REACT\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at D:\REACT\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:418:10
    at D:\REACT\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:293:13
    at D:\REACT\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\REACT\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\REACT\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\REACT\my-app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

i do some changes in openssl but error does not resolve